# SWRevealViewController - push view controller from side menu

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

I've set up my app using the SWRevealViewController and it's working fine but I want to change how it works. At the moment I have the following views on the same level:

- Home
- View A
- View B

But I want:

- Home

  - View A
  - View B

I still want Home, View A, View B to be in the menu but when clicking on View A or View B it gets pushed onto Home. And in the navigation bar it has a back button instead of the menu button.

Is this possible using SWRevealViewController?

Answer (score 7):

in **objective-C**

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
SWRevealViewController *main = (SWRevealViewController *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SWRevealViewController"];
[self presentViewController:main animated:YES completion:nil];
```

in **swift**  -- it automatically open the your root view controller of SWL

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let main = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SWRevealViewController") as! UIViewController //SWRevealViewController
self.presentViewController(main, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an [answer](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController/issues/644) and hopefully it helps someone reading this. It has both ways, SideMenu when you have a tabBarController or only a NavigationController. Posting snippet from answer, which worked for me.

**With TabBar Controller:**

```
UITabBarController *tbc = (UITabBarController *)self.revealViewController.frontViewController;
    UINavigationController *nc = tbc.selectedViewController;
    [nc pushViewController:myVC animated:NO];
    [self.revealViewController setFrontViewPosition:FrontViewPositionLeft animated:YES];
```

**With Navigation Controller:**

```
UINavigationController *frontVC = (UINavigationController *)self.revealViewController.frontViewController;
[frontVC pushViewController: yourVC animated:NO];
[self.revealViewController pushFrontViewController:frontVC animated:YES];
```